# Code an SQL Trigger that raises an exception

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to code a SQL trigger that raises an error if the price of an item is set to a value that is more than four times the value of the least expensive item.
Name of table is itemType and name of price column is price.
This is what I tried but I can't seem to get it working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER harekrishna
BEFORE INSERT ON itemType 
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
hPrice NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT price INTO hPrice 
  FROM itemType
  WHERE price = :newrow.price; 
IF hPrice > 4 * MIN(price)
  raise_application_error(-20000, (‘Price of item’ |:newrow.price |‘greater than 4 times the least expensive item’); 
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong quote characters, missing `THEN` and missing `END` in last line. Try that one and let me know if you have more erros.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER harekrishna
    BEFORE INSERT ON itemType 
    REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    hPrice NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    SELECT min(price) INTO hPrice 
      FROM itemType; 
    IF :newrow.price > 4 * hPrice  THEN
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Price of item' ||:newrow.price ||'greater than 4 times the least expensive item'); 
    END IF;
    END;
```

Also logic of this select make no sense so I changed it to get min price and in if just use `:newrow`.

Comment: 8/122  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
  following:
  ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
  <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4 likec between overlaps || multiset year day member
  submultiset
  The symbol ")" was substituted for ";" to continue.

Comment: @ShakiraWeloveyou Try now there was one bracket too much in `raise`